# C# Winforms Custom control help 

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am looking for a free control in C# which allows me to show a set of images in a List like a preview (Eg PDF pages preview). I tried ListView control but it does not allow me to set bigger image size. Please advice

Comment: i am looking for a winforms control

Comment: A `ListView` works just fine. You can make the icons as big as you like, as long as you set it to "LargeIcon" view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ListView-ImageList combination to achieve that purpose.

Just set the ImageList's `ImageSize` property to something large, say `96, 96` and set the ListView's `LargeImageList` property to the ImageList.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a repeater?

here's a link returned on the first page of a quick google search that demonstrates one way to do this: http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=157&Desc=Asp.Net-Image-Dropdownlist

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for Winforms control. Not ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

There is the [ImageListView](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/) control. (I am the owner of the project.)

[image: ImageListView Control Screenshot]

Comment: I just looked at your project and I find it quite interesting. Good going on that!

Answer (score 0):

How about a Panel with images in it? You can set it up to render as a scrollable div (if you're targeting ASP.NET, which I think you are), or if this is WinForms, you just set it to have scrollbars.

Understand, though, that unless you have pre-made thumbnails for your images, showing a preview of the image will require loading the whole image and downsizing it to show as a thumb. So, except for the real estate it will take, you may not be saving much by "previewing" images.